# Customer Survey: Is the main reason for a rating equivalent to the rating of the main reason?

Tags: survey

In a customer survey, customers are in a first step ased to rate the experience and in the second step to pick the one main reason for the rating.

My question is if the main reason for rating the experience is equivalent to the rating of the main reason?

Example:
Rating of the experience: 4 out of 5 stars.
Main reason for the rating: Service.

Can it therefore be concluded the service is rated with 4 out of 5 stars? If not, why? How can a person with no statistical or marketing background be convinced?

Answer (score 0):

No because that's not the question you asked, that rating could be interpreted as the rating for the full experience (which service is part of). Say there's 3 categories, service might have 5/5, price 3/5 and speed 4/5. The end result for that person might be 4/5.